# Django: list all reverse relations of a model

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I would like my django application to serve a list of any model's fields (this will help the GUI build itself).

Imagine the classes (ignore the fact that all field of `Steps` could be in `Item`, I have my reasons :-) )

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class Steps(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField('Item', related_name='steps')
    design = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    prototype = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    production = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, when I want to list a model's fields:

```
def get_fields(model):
    return model._meta.fields + model._meta.many_to_many
```

But I would also like to get the list of "related" one-to-one foreign keys to my models. In my case `Item.steps` would not be in that list.

I have found that `model._meta.get_all_field_names` does include all the related fields.

But when I call `Item._meta.get_field_by_name('steps')` it returns a tuple holding a `RelatedObject`, which does not tell me instantly whether this is a *single* relation or a one-to-many (I want to list only reversed one-to-one relations).

Also, I can use this bit of code:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor
reversed_f_keys = [attr for attr in Item.__dict__.values() \
                  if isinstance(attr, SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor)]
```

But I'm not very satisfied with this.

Any help, idea, tips are welcome!

Cheers

Comment: So yeah, I have a potential solution for my need, but I would be pleased to have a better one :)

Answer (score 30):

This was changed (in 1.8 I think) and Olivier's answer doesn't work anymore. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api), the new way is

```
[f for f in Item._meta.get_fields()
    if f.auto_created and not f.concrete]
```

This includes one-to-one, many-to-one, and many-to-many.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the deprecation. It'll save me a headache when I upgrade to 1.10 :) (stuck with 1.6 for now though)

Comment: God I can't believe I've never thought of this before, so if it is auto_created and not concrete it will always be a reverse relationship?

Comment: There's a problem wit this solution, it also lists forward manytomany relationships that have a throughtable, I found a way to filter them but its very tedious

Comment: The [field attribute reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#field-attribute-reference) helps to determine the correct set of filters.

Comment: @Mojimi: Good question. A reverse relation appears on your model like magic, so it is `auto_created`. The actual database column holding the foreign keys is not part of your model (it is part of the related model), so it is *not* `concrete`. On the other hand, e.g. the `id` field is also `auto_created` but it *is* `concrete`, and a `ForeignKey` field is *not* `auto_created` but it *is* `concrete`. I wonder if e.g. `f.is_relation and f.auto_created` could also work.

Answer (score 3):

I've found out that there are methods of `Model._meta` that can give me what I want.

```
my_model = get_model('app_name','model_name')
# Reverse foreign key relations
reverse_fks = my_model._meta.get_all_related_objects()
# Reverse M2M relations
reverse_m2ms = my_model._meta.get_all_related_many_to_many_objects()
```

By parsing the content of the relations, I can guess whether the "direct" field was a `OneToOneField` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into this answer as a starting point to identify reversed relationships for a model instance.

So, I noticed that when you get all the fields using `instance._meta.get_fields()`, those that are direct relationships, which are 3 types (`ForeignKey`, `ManyToMany`, `OneTone`), their parent class (`field.__class__.__bases__`) is `django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey`.

However, those that are reverse relationships inherit from `django.db.models.fields.reverse_related.ForeignObjectRel`. And if you take a look at this class, it has:

```
auto_created = True
concrete = False
```

So you could identify those by the attributes mentioned in the top-rated answer or by asking `isinstance(field, ForeignObjectRel`.

Another thing I could notice is that those reverse relationships have a `field` attribute which points to the direct relationship generating that reverse relationship.

Additionally, in order to exclude the fields instantiating the `through` table, those have `through` and `through_fields` attributes

Answer (score 0):

And what about this :

```
oneToOneFieldNames = [
    field_name 
    for field_name in Item._meta.get_all_field_names() 
    if isinstance(
        getattr(
            Item._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0], 
            'field', 
            None
        ), 
        models.OneToOneField
    )
]
```

RelatedObject may have a Field attribute for relations. You just have to check if this is a OneToOne field and you can retrieve only what you want

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Django Rest Framework, you could use something like that for your obj:

```
from rest_framework.utils import model_meta
info = model_meta.get_field_info(obj)
for field in obj.__class__.__dict__.keys():
    if field in info.relations and info.relations[field].to_many and info.relations[field].reverse:
        #print all reverse relations
        print(field)
```