# Flag as Deleted (Django) (flag in all tables) or (in one)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project where there is a lot of use of foreign keys
Table A has two or more than two foreign keys say(B and c) and B have two other foreign keys (D,E) similary C also have several foreign keys in DB

I am using Django.and want a soft delete.
Since when I use on cascade delete it will delete all the other records in the table linked to foreign keys.

So what is the best way to deal with such things. What I did was tried to mimic cascading feature by making flag field in all table and as soon as record in D,E is deleted(or flag is set to False) , record in B also get flag=False and thus finally A

should i Prefer this approach or do I have to set flag = False in one db and have to check each anf every time whetther tha flag is false or not for all the foreign keys linked to it. I think I didn't explain the problem well but I hope you get the idea what I was trying to say

How I implemented former using recursive approach. For getting reverse relations I got the code fom https://stackoverflow.com/a/42627288/7698247

```
def deleteObject(a):
    print("deleting", a, a._meta.model)
    a.flag = False
    a.save()
    # a = myobject()
    b = [f for f in a._meta.model._meta.get_fields() if f.auto_created and not f.concrete]
    b = [el for el in b if type(el) != ManyToManyRel]

    model_names = [x.related_model for x in b]

    # print(model_names)

    accesor_names = [i.get_accessor_name() for i in b]

    # print(accesor_names)

    querysets = [a.__getattribute__(accesor_names[i]).all() for i in range(len(accesor_names))]

    # print(querysets)

    for queryset in querysets:
        for instance in queryset:
            try:
                deleteObject(instance)
            except Exception as E:
                print("error is ", E)
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                print("in line no", exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

This helped me to use the same function for deleting any object from any model and filtering any DB based on the flag

for e.g X.objects.filter(flag=True)

Comment: Did you consider  `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` in your model's attribute ?

Comment: @angrysumit I still want to track the relationship if required in future

Comment: There might be other ways, depending on what behaviour you eventually want to show to your users. If the delete operation should just be reversible or the deleted objects auditable, consider letting the delete cascade actually happen (so users see the deletion without having to filter everything on your flag) and make a backup in a different model of all the deleted objects using signals (post_delete or delete_related signals). The backup could just be a JSON representation of each object, including their pk and foreignkeys.

Comment: seems a quite good option, will consider it for sure. Seems much better.Can you also tell what difficulties I may face in future if I recursively change the flag for all these related objects and filter by True

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) built into Django. Using the delete-related signals you should be able to achieve what you are looking to do in a much more elegant way.

Comment: Yes I know signals , Can you explain how to use that in this particular case

Comment: the problem with the signals is that if he doesn't actually delete any of the objects, the signals won't trigger apart from the first.