# Django: How to determine if an object is referenced by any other object?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

### summary

In Django, what is the simplest way to determine if there are any objects in our database that refer to a given object?

### details

Consider this minimal example from Django's [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference):

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can we determine if there are **any** objects, so *not only* `Article` objects, that point to a given `Reporter` object, either through a `OneToOneField`, a `ForeignKey`, or a `ManyToManyField`?

In other words, we want to determine if there are any [reverse relations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17328910) to the given object.

For `Article` it is easy, we can just get e.g. `reporter.article_set.count()`, but other models may be added later which also point to `Reporter`, and these will also have to be taken into account.

### example use-case

An example use case is where we want to prevent modification as soon as an object is being referenced by *any* other object. Or we could use it to enforce a kind of behavior similar to the `on_delete=models.PROTECT` mechanism.

Comment: Hey, have a look at the `contenttype` framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/. A call like `ContentType.objects.all()` should allow you to retrieve all the models in your system. You can build from there...

Comment: Somewhat similar, but does not answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19512187

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution, using the `Model._meta` [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model), but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. Hoping for better answers.

Basically, given an object, we get a list of its reverse relations, then, for each of those, we check if there are any objects in the relation.

```
# just any given reporter object
obj = Reporter.objects.first()
# assume no references to obj
obj_has_reverse = False
# skip for new objects (i.e. those not yet saved to database)
if obj.id is not None:  
    # reverse relation "fields" on the Reporter model are auto-created and
    # not concrete
    for reverse in [f for f in obj._meta.get_fields() 
                    if f.auto_created and not f.concrete]:
        # in case the related name has been customized
        name = reverse.get_accessor_name()
        # one-to-one requires a special approach
        has_reverse_one_to_one = reverse.one_to_one and hasattr(obj, name)
        has_reverse_other = not reverse.one_to_one and getattr(obj, name).count()
        if has_reverse_one_to_one or has_reverse_other:
            obj_has_reverse = True
```

Note that a reverse relation for `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` returns a [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager), so we can check e.g. the `count()`. However, a reverse relation for `OneToOneField` does not return a `RelatedManager`. It raises a `DoesNotExist` exception if there is no related object, as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships).
Also see the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L149) for `reverse_related`.

Comment: you probably meant to change `Terms` to `Reporter`?

Comment: @dirkgroten: Right. Well spotted. Thanks! Fixing it now.

Comment: Mmmm, if there is a onetoone relation with null=True your code will return True even if related.reporter is None?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Let's say `SomeModel` has a `OneToOneField` pointing to `Reporter`. If this has `null=True` and there are no `SomeModel` objects at all, then `hasattr(reporter, 'somemodel_set')` will return `False`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have to try, I think  if you do `reporter.somemodel_set` you would get None if there is no `SomeModel` related. But if you  can `reporter.somemodel_set` is because there is a `somemodel_set` attribute.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: No, it is a `OneToOneField`, so `reporter.somemodel_set` will raise an exception if there is no associated `SomeModel` object. There is an example of this specific behavior in the [docs for one-to-one relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) (search for `ObjectDoesNotExist`). They explicitly suggest using `hasattr`.

Comment: Yeah it will rise the excepion, but again I have to try, when you do `reporter.somemodel_set` and you get an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exeption instead of an "attribute not found" error that tell me the attribute is there. In fact ir also tell me that attribute is some kind of descriptor.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Have a look at django's own [one-to-one getter test](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/tests/one_to_one/tests.py#L30), which uses `hasattr`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: The `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` is defined on the `RevereseOneToOneDescriptor` class, and has both `AttributeError` and `ObjectDoesNotExist` as its bases, as you can see [in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L340).